# Calculate $\operatorname{tg}( \alpha), $ if $\frac{\pi}{2} < \alpha<\pi$ and $\sin( \alpha)= \frac{2\sqrt{29}}{29}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Calculate $\operatorname{tg}( \alpha), $ if $\frac{\pi}{2} < \alpha<\pi$ and $\sin( \alpha)= \frac{2\sqrt{29}}{29}$. Please provide a hint.
I know that $\operatorname{tg}( \alpha)=\frac{\sin( \alpha)}{\cos( \alpha)}$ and $\sin^2( \alpha)+\cos^2( \alpha)=1$, but still can't get the answer from there.

Comment: Compute first $\tan^2(a)$ and take the square root  and take care about the quadrant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\frac\pi2<\alpha<\pi$,$$\cos(\alpha)=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\alpha)}=-\frac5{\sqrt{29}},$$and therefore$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}=-\frac25.$$

Answer (score 1):

José Carlos Santos provided an algebraic answer; I'll provide a more geometric one.

Try drawing a picture. Since $\alpha$ is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, it lies in Quadrant II. The triangle that becomes its reference triangle has an "opposite" (vertical) side length of $2 \sqrt{29}$ and the hypotenuse has length $29$.

[image]

From here you can find $\tan(\beta)$ in the reference triangle (the acute angle next to $\alpha$) - you will probably need to use the Pythagorean theorem. Then account for the sign of tangent in Quadrant II to get what $\tan(\alpha)$ would be.

I'll leave the calculations and justifying these steps to you.